# How can I respond to events raised by programmatically created UI elements?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a board game for a piece of coursework. For the board, I'm using some nested For loops running through a 2D array to generate a "Space" object at each square.

The Space object contains a picturebox and some data about that space.

How can I handle events caused by clicking on the generated picturebox without having to hard-code it for each space?

I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023343/how-to-get-windows-for-to-raise-mouseclick-event-for-programatically-created-pic) question seems to address this, but it's in C# and I couldn't translate it to VB.Net.

Edit:
This is how the board is generated

```
 Dim board(23, 24) As Space

 Private Sub GenerateBoard()

    Dim spaceSize As New Size(30, 30)
    Dim spaceLocation As New Point
    Dim validity As Boolean

    For Y = 0 To 24
        For X = 0 To 23
            spaceLocation.X = 6 + (31 * X)
            spaceLocation.Y = 6 + (31 * Y)

            If validSpaces(Y).Contains(X + 1) Then
                validity = True
            Else
                validity = False
            End If

            board(X, Y) = New Space(validity, spaceSize, spaceLocation)
            Me.Controls.Add(board(X, Y).imageBox)
            board(X, Y).imageBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            board(X, Y).imageBox.BringToFront()
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Space Class:

```
Public Class Space

Dim _active As Boolean
Dim _imageBox As PictureBox

Public Sub New(ByVal activeInput As Boolean, ByVal size As Size, ByVal location As Point)
    _active = activeInput
    _imageBox = New PictureBox
    With _imageBox
        .Size = size
        .Location = location
        .Visible = False
    End With
End Sub

Property active As Boolean
    Get
        Return _active
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _active = value
    End Set
End Property

Property imageBox As PictureBox
    Get
        Return _imageBox
    End Get
    Set(value As PictureBox)
        _imageBox = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub highlight()
    With _imageBox
        .Image = My.Resources.Highlighted_slab
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please always share what you have tried and what is your exact problem. Nobody wants to do your homework but of course we will help you fixing real problems. So: What does not work?

Comment: @Mr.VVOO Well I'm not sure how to approach the problem. At the moment I have 600 programatically generated pictureboxes stored in a 2D array, and no way of handling click events from them. I tried creating an event to handle click events on the array, which didn't work (ie: `Sub space_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles board().Click`). The only other "solution" I can think of is to manually write a routine to handle each picturebox, which would be exceptionally inefficient.

Comment: So then maybe you should provide some code that others can see where  and how to start.

Comment: *but it's in C# and I couldn't translate it to VB.Net.*  C# and VB.NET was developed by same team, so it pretty mush same things. And `generatedControl.Click += generatedControl_ClickHandler;` in VB.NET `AddHandler generatedControl.Click, AddressOf generatedControl_ClickHandler`

Comment: @Fabio Okay, where would that go? Just after I've declared the array to hold them, or after I've initialised the space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all controls created by designer(textbox, label...) a generated by code too, but VisualStudio write this for you. If you open Designer file(`yourForm.Designer.vb`), then you can see all code how to generate a controls.

If you want a create event handler for your `pictureBox` , then:

```
//Initialize control
Private WithEvents _imageBox as PictureBox
```

Then create a event handler method:

```
Private Sub imageBox_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    //Your code
End Sub
```

Then in VB.NET you can assign a Event handler to the Event in two ways

first: In class constructor after you created a pictureBox( `New PictureBox()`) add

```
AddHandler Me._imageBox, AddressOf Me.imageBox_Click
```

second: On line we you created a event handler add next:

```
Private Sub imageBox_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles _imageBox.Click
    //Your code
End Sub
```

And remember add your pictureBox to form controls `YourForm.Controls.Add(spaceInstance.ImageBox)`